# How do I change the size of an area during simulation time

Tags: anylogic

I'm looking to create an area that is re-sizable. I have a slider for the area length and I have the slider action set to `preCheckArea.setSize(waitAreaLength,30);`

I receive the following error:

[image]

Does this mean that its not possible and I have to exit the sim to resize?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, elements like this cannot be changed dynamically at runtime.

However, you can create them programmatically during runtime using the API (check the help). So when you change your size, you destroy the existing object, recreate it with a new size and re-add it to the network.

Not straight-forward but possible